# EMQX on docker-multiple device cluster

Tags: docker, emqx

I'm trying to run EQMX docker image on many different machines and build a cluster with them. I have tried using the static list method and the dns discovery method.

They are under the same network but because docker creates its own network they dont see each other. How can I make a cluster out of them without installing EQMX on the machine itself? How can I make docker not attach the container to a virtual network? Should I publish a certain port so that the containers are visible to each other?

Comment: Did you tried with docker swarm?

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being to expose the container to the host network `--network="host"` and defining EMQX auto clustering to use mcast.
After that got an error similar to `Cannot get connection id for node` that ended up being related to the node name that did not have the proper format `<name>@<IP address>`